# Spring Installation on Mac

Tags: java, spring

I'm learning `spring` before I learn `spring-boot` I wish to install spring from  Spring.
I have downloaded and unzipped, I need help as to where to place the folder so I can start working using a `import org.springframework.stereotype.Component` on a Mac. 
 I know this is trivial question but I haven't found an installation of this kind, majority of the tutorials use *spring.io* to generate a zip file, or use maven to do the installation.

Comment: You above all need and IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly let me tell you about `CLASSPATH`, according to the `oracle` website

> *The Classpath tells the JDK tool where to find third-party and user defined classes that are not extensions or part of the Java platform.*

On a Mac you need to type `echo $CLASSPATH` to see if you have any CLASSPATH set up, if you have never worked with third party classes this will be blank.

To add to `CLASSPATH` run the following command in the terminal
`export CLASSPATH=/Users/{Path}` this will clear all the classpaths , if you want to add to existing classpath run `export CLASSPATH={$CLASSPATH}:/Users/{Path}`
You can find a detailed article on this topic [here](https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/java-classpath-know-it-and-use-it-correctly-2cf6e4dc87ee)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to use a build tool like `Maven` or `Gradle` to have the ability to add Spring Core to your project.
otherwise, you need to download the jar file and add it to the classpath.